# array value changing unexpectedly after recv()

Tags: c, sockets, recv

after i run the server, i run two instances of client. Now first time i run the client, the received data is saved into array[0], but when i run the second client, the value of array[0] is overwritten with the new value surprisingly. The new data shouls be saved in array[1] instead of overwriting. what mistake am i making?

char *Array[100];
int ArrayCount = 0; are global variables.

```
void *server()
{
int listenfd = 0;
connfd = 0;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(port));

if(bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
{
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
}

listen(listenfd, 10);

while(1)
{
    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);

    printf("data in Array[0] before recv : %s\n",Array[0]);

    int ns;
    char revdData[2000];
    bzero(revdData,2000);
    ns = recv(connfd,revdData,2000,0);
    close(connfd);

    printf("data in Array[0] after recv : %s\n",Array[0]);

    Array[ArrayCount] = revdData;
    ArrayCount = ArrayCount+1;
 }
}
```

client code

```
void *client()
{

int soctype = SOCK_STREAM;
struct hostent *hp, *gethostbyname();
struct sockaddr_in servR;
struct servent *seR;
int tempSocket;
char *host = "localhost";

if ((tempSocket = socket(AF_INET, soctype, 0)) < 0)
{
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
}

if ((hp = gethostbyname(host)) == NULL)
{
    exit(1);
}

servR.sin_family = AF_INET;
memcpy(&servR.sin_addr, hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
if (isdigit(*port))
{
    servR.sin_port = htons(atoi(port));
}
else
{
    if ((seR = getservbyname(port, (char *)NULL)) < (struct servent *) 0)
    {
        perror(port);
        exit(1);
    }
    servR.sin_port = seR->s_port;
}


if (connect(tempSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &servR, sizeof(servR)) < 0)
{
    perror("connect");
    exit(1);
}

char input[100];
fgets(input,100,stdin);
int n;
n=send(tempSocket,input,100,0);
if (n < 0)
{
    error("Send");
}
}
```

output is as follows:

```
data in Array[0] before recv : (null)
data in Array[0] after recv : (null)
data in Array[0] before recv : 1st Instance
data in Array[0] after recv : 2nd Instance
```

ideally data after recv should be "1st instance", because i am printing array[0].

Comment: `struct hostent *hp, *gethostbyname();` is bad. Instead, `#include` the appropriate header file. Or even better, replace `getservbyname()` and `gethostbyname()` by the newer `getaddrinfo()` and `getnameinfo()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assignment in the server code is not doing what you want:

```
Array[ArrayCount] = revdData;
```

This is invalid code, because `revdData` is a local array with scope delimited to `server()`. The assignment doesn't copy the array, it copies the pointer to its first element. So, by the time you return from `server()`, `Array` contains a pointer to an invalid location - the memory for the local `revdData` array is invalid. What happens next is unknown. Usually, since you'll be calling `server()` again, it is very likely that the same memory space is being reused for the new `revdData` array, so it ends up overwriting what you don't want.

To fix it, you must either allocate memory in `Array[ArrayCount]` and then use `strncpy`, or use `strndup`.

Here's what you can do with `strncpy`:

```
Array[ArrayCount] = malloc(ns);
strncpy(Array[ArrayCount], revdData, (size_t) ns);
```

Also, you can change `ns` from `int` to `ssize_t`, which is the return type of `recv`.

If you want to use `strndup`, you don't need to explicitly use `malloc`, however, if your data contains null bytes, it will not copy beyond that point, and if it doesn't, it will add a null byte in the duplicated string, which might not be what you want.

Note that this approach introduces the problem of memory management; at some point, you have to free the memory allocated for each position taken in `Array`. You are responsible for doing this, although in small programs you can usually rely on the fact that all allocated memory is freed by the operating system upon program termination.

Answer (score 1):

You are just copying the pointer `revdData` into `Array[i]`. hence, all your `Array` elements just point to `revdData`.

You should allocate some memory to your `Array` elements and copy the value of `revdData` into `Array[ArrayCount]`.

```
// Just after you recv
Array[ArrayCount] = malloc(sizeof(char) * ns);
strncpy(Array[ArrayCount], revdData, (size_t)ns);
ArrayCount++;


// Free allocated memory before you exit
for(i = 0; i < ArrayCount; i++) {
    free(Array[ArrayCount]);
    Array[ArrayCount] = 0;
}
```

Please refer to some tutorials for better client/server designs.

Comment: This won't work. You can't pass `sizeof(Array[ArrayCount])` to `strncpy`, since that will evaluate to the size of a `char *` - not what you want. `Array[ArrayCount]` is not an array, it's a pointer. You should replace that with `ns`.